# How do I rename multiple files which have a slightly different extension?

Tags: bash, filenames, rename

I have multiple files which all have a similar naming pattern like:

```
{filename}.jpeg{random number}
```

I want to rename these files so that their extension is just .jpeg. How can I do this?

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

If you have Larry Wall's perl rename

```
rename 's/[.]jpeg[0-9]*/.jpeg/' *.jpeg[0-9]*
```

if you have only the Util-Linux rename that won't work.

You could use a for loop in bash

```
for n in *.jpeg[0-9]*
do mv -i "$n" "${n%%.jpeg[0-9]*}.jpeg"
done
```

`${var%%pattern}` is a [standard parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) that expands to the value of `var`, with the (longest) trailing part matching `pattern` removed. So, if `n` is `foo.jpeg123`, `${n%%.jpeg[0-9*}` is `foo`. (`foo.jpeg1abc` would also result in `foo`.)

Comment: Could you please explain your answer a bit? (I'd personally like to understand the `n%%`). Thanks.

Comment: @Biggybi, there.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using `zsh`'s `zmv` here which would guard against potential conflicts (like there being both a `file.jpeg1` and `file.jpeg2` files in the current directory) before doing *any* rename.

In `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(*.jpeg)<->' '$1'
```

Where `<->` (`<x-y>` number range matching here without boundaries) matches any sequence of decimal digits, same as `[0-9]##`.

(remove the `-n` for dry-run when happy).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only a single `.jpeg` substring in each name and that you'd like to remove everything after that substring (no matter if it's a number or some other string), using a standard shell loop:

```
for name in *.jpeg*; do
    mv -i -- "$name" "${name%.jpeg*}.jpeg"
done
```

The parameter substitution `${name%.jpeg*}` would delete `.jpeg` and anything following it from the value of `$name`.  We then add the `.jpeg` string to the result of that substitution to create the new filename.

The `mv -i --` bit will invoke `mv` in such a way that it will ask for confirmation before overwriting an existing name.  The `--` is to protect the following filename from accidentally being recognised as a set of options if the name starts with a dash (`--` signals the end of command line options).